# Javascript didn't load in my html

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i copy the codes from this website completely unchanged 
-> `enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/puJ6G/

But the button doesn't work for me. When i click the + and -, nothing happen to the number. 
This is my code in the netbeans.
Is my netbean problem or something missing in the javascript?

[the html, css and javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN1mP.png)

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Instead of an image of the code, please post the code (as text) as part of your answer.

Comment: agreed with @Matansh same here!

Comment: Press F12 and see which errors you get in console and post them here please.

Comment: Just a quick tip, try following these steps for asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Good luck bro! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure on what exactly you are asking but I understood it like that:

You want to use the code from the JSFiddle in your own project and it does not work.

If that is the case, I think you forgot to add a reference to JQuery in your code.

Add this to your HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

And see if that fixes your problem.

However if it does not fix it, please edit your post with the full code.

Comment: Thank you, i don't know that i need to add the src thing in the html :)

Comment: @LeongJC Did it work? If it did and if you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it :)